# Splitting a large integer Value from a list into smaller integers in multiple lists

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Say I have an int of `123456789` in list `a` but I want to split it into 4 lists like `h=[12] m=[34] s=[56] ms=[789]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best way but you can do it like this:

```
#int in list to string
a_temp = str(a[0])
#empty lists
h = [0]
m = [0]
s = [0]
ms = [0]
#substrings to int in lists
h[0] = int(a_temp[0:2])
m[0] = int(a_temp[2:4])
s[0] = int(a_temp[4:6])
ms[0] = int(a_temp[6:])
```